# How to get the MyController Show url programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

(Using MVC 2)

From inside my controller action, I need to display the url:

```
/MyController/Show/123
```

How can I generate this url using the helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
public ActionResult Show(int id )
{
    var completeURL = Request.RawUrl;
    var relativePath = Request.Path;
    var uriObject = Request.Url;
}
```

---

From other controller:

```
var url = Url.Action("Show", "MyController", new {id = 123});
```

But maybe you just need to redirect?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Show", "MyController", new {id = 123});
}
```

Comment: I want to use the mvc helpers, so I can generate this url from other actions not the one currently running. i.e. The 'index' action is running, but inside it I want to generate the show action's url.

Comment: but I wrote in my question "How can I generate this url using the helpers?"